# Ask parameter before Locust tests start

Tags: python, locust, webui

I using Locust for perfomance tests.
I realy have few working scripts on it and now i need another one which will ask parameter before start. I need it in web ui, because we using locust as a service. Could anybody help with it?

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at custom arguments? They automatically become available in the UI.

https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/extending-locust.html#custom-arguments